# Implicit intent does not find activity if data type is specified

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to make an example of invoking an activity using implicit intent.
[Intents and Intent Filters](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#kotlin)
I do it according to the code of the example indicated here.

```
getSecondActivity.setOnClickListener() {

        val gameNameStr = getTextFromView(gamerName)
        val gameStatusStr = getTextFromView(gameStatus)
        if (gameNameStr != null && gameStatus != null) {


            val sendIntent = Intent().apply {
                action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
                putExtra(GAMER_NAME, gameNameStr)
                putExtra(GAME_STATUS, gameStatusStr)
                type = "text/plain"
            }
            //Verify the original intent will resolve to at least one activity
            if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                startActivity(sendIntent)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "No Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

I specified filters in the manifest.

```
 <activity android:name=".ShowInfoFromFirst">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

At startup, a message is displayed that no matching activity was found. If I remove the type, then everything works. I came across a description in the class Intent.java
"type -- Specifies an explicit type (a MIME type) of the
intent data.  Normally the type is inferred from the data itself.
By setting this attribute, **you disable that evaluation and force
an explicit type "
Then I do not understand why the example does not work for me.